# Java Kafka Consumer - Timeout for the Consumer

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I am trying to build a Kafka Consumer, which is expected to stay alive for about 60 minutes. That is, poll for messages for 60 minutes and then exit from polling a topic. IS there any property that defines a timeout for this use case? or should I bring in the programmatic approach to stop the polling after a specific time?

Kafka Consumer stop polling after certain time.

Answer (score 1):

If you use Spring (that's what you tagged), you can stop/start the listener container(s) whenever you want.

There is nothing built in to automatically stop after some time.